# How to do both inclusive and exclusive routing?

Tags: reactjs, react-router

I need to be able to display the component on the home path "/" while I have "/signIn" modal up. However, after my user is signed in, I would like to replace the "/" component with the "/internal" component. I know how to use  to render components exclusively, but I need a solution where I am rendering both inclusively and exclusively. My signIn modal must appear above the "/" component, and after the user is signed in I need the "/" component to be switched with the "/internal" component. I am only being able to do one or the other, is there a way to use both inclusive and exclusive routing in React-Router 4? Thank you.

What I tried:

```
<Route path="/" component={ExternalContainer} />
<Route path="/signIn" component={SignInModal} />
<Switch>
    <Route path="/" component={ExternalContainer} />
    <Route path="/internal" component={InternalContainer} />
</Switch>
```

What I have now but does not work:

```
<Route path="/" component={ExternalContainer} />
<Route path="/signIn" component={SignInModal} />
<Route path="/internal" component={InternalContainer} />
```

Comment: Just provided a solution for you below. Did you have any luck integrating this feature?

Answer (score 0):

I think you are overcomplicating your routing structure. In theory, if you want to use a modal for your `SignInModal` component, then it does not need its own `Route`. You can just toggle its display within your `ExternalContainer` component. Then upon filling out the `form` and clicking the submit button in your `SignInModal`, just redirect to the  `InternalContainer`.

See a very basic integration like this: https://codesandbox.io/s/old-snowflake-djbc3

### Working code:

*index.js*

```
import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
import { BrowserRouter, Route } from "react-router-dom";
import ExternalContainer from "./ExternalContainer";
import InternalContainer from "./InternalContainer";

import "./styles.css";

function App() {
  return (
    <BrowserRouter>
      <Route path="/" component={ExternalContainer} exact />
      <Route path="/internal" component={InternalContainer} />
    </BrowserRouter>
  );
}

const rootElement = document.getElementById("root");
ReactDOM.render(<App />, rootElement);
```

*ExternalContainer.js*

```
import React from "react";
import SignInModal from "./SignInModal";

class ExternalContainer extends React.Component {
  state = {
    modalOpen: false
  };

  toggleModal = () => {
    this.setState({
      modalOpen: !this.state.modalOpen
    });
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <h4>Welcome to the App</h4>
        <button onClick={this.toggleModal}>Sign In</button>
        <SignInModal
          open={this.state.modalOpen}
          toggleModal={this.toggleModal}
        />
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default ExternalContainer;
```

*SignInModal.js*

```
import React from "react";
import Modal from "react-modal";
import { withRouter } from "react-router-dom";

class SignInModal extends React.Component {
  state = {
    username: "",
    password: ""
  };

  handleOnChange = e => {
    this.setState({
      [e.target.name]: e.target.value
    });
  };

  handleOnSubmit = e => {
    e.preventDefault();
    const { username, password } = this.state;
    if (username && password) {
      this.props.history.push("/internal");
    }
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <Modal
        isOpen={this.props.open}
        onRequestClose={this.props.toggleModal}
        style={{
          overlay: {
            background: "rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3)"
          },
          content: {
            background: "white",
            top: "45%",
            left: "50%",
            right: "auto",
            bottom: "auto",
            transform: "translate(-50%,-50%)",
            width: "200px",
            textAlign: "center"
          }
        }}
        ariaHideApp={false}
      >
        <form onSubmit={this.handleOnSubmit}>
          <div>
            <label>Name</label>{" "}
            <input name="username" onChange={this.handleOnChange} />
          </div>
          <div>
            <label>Password</label>{" "}
            <input name="password" onChange={this.handleOnChange} />
          </div>
          <button type="submit">Sign In</button>
        </form>
      </Modal>
    );
  }
}
export default withRouter(SignInModal);
```

*InternalContainer.js*

```
import React from "react";

const InternalContainer = () => {
  return (
    <div>
      <h4>You have reached the internal container</h4>
    </div>
  );
};

export default InternalContainer;
```